# How to instantiate a Scala object using reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10, scala-2.11, scala-reflect

I have some code that uses reflection to instantiate a Java or Scala class, allowing a user to specify the name:
Assume that `loadIt` below is a hypothetical method defined using [this approach](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077572/learn-java/java-tip-70--create-objects-from-jar-files-.html#sthash.pgWuhVn3.dpuf).

```
def getInstance(name:String, jar:String) = {
   val c:Class[_] = loadIt(name, jar) // load class from the jar
   c.newInstance.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] // return new instance of the class
}
```

This works fine if `name` is a Scala class, but not if it is an object. 
Say I define an object:

```
object Foo
```

and call it as:

```
getInstance("Foo", "someJar.jar")
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: Foo
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:364)
```

Is there any way I can properly instantiate the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer:

Refer to [this link](http://3x14159265.tumblr.com/post/57543163324/playing-with-scala-reflection). Added the following code:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def getObjectInstance(clsName: String):AnyRef = {
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val module = mirror.staticModule(clsName)
  mirror.reflectModule(module).instance.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
}
val c:Class[_] = loadIt("Foo", "someJar.jar") // ok 
val o = try c.newInstance.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] catch {
    case i:java.lang.InstantiationException => getObjectInstance("Foo")
}
// works
```